# Modal view controller inside master tableview (and dismiss keyboard)

Tags: uitextfield, uitableview

I know this is a very popular issue, but i´m having a hard time...so if anyone could help, it would most appreciate:

Im my master tableview (that i have made in storyboard) i have a plus button and every time the user presses that button, a picker view appears...depending on the selection in the picker view, a modal view appears (for this modal view, i have dragged a simple view controller in storyboard and gave it a storyboard id). Each modal view has textfields, and i want to dismiss the keyboard every time the user enters something...to create the modal view i have done this:

```
CobTableview *produtoCob =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cobId"];
    produtoCob.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:produtoCob animated:YES completion:nil];
    produtoCob.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, 512); //do this after     presentModalViewController
    produtoCob.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
    produtoCob.managedObjectContext = self.contextProd;
```

How can i resolve this?

Comment: download your pdf sample code from http://ge.tt/3uavVb41/v/0?c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To everyone that has the same issue...i found out that you need both methods in your modal view controller class :

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal 
return NO  
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
([textField resignFirstResponder];     
return yes
```